# ¿Como guardar un valor en un vector/array en Lenguaje ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador

hola amigos soy nuevo aquí, estoy buscando ayuda sobre ¿Como guardar un valor en un vector/array en Lenguaje ensamblador?, si alguien sabe algo por favor ayúdeme con un ejemplo o alguna informacion, llevo horas atascado.

Comment: no soy un experto en ensamblador asi que solo te puedo compartir un ejemplo de una pregunta en ingles:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899731/arrays-in-assembly